# How to speed up my optimisation model (Pyomo with Gurobi)

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I'm new to optimisation (operation research).

I am looking to speed up my model.

Currently running a MILP model with Pyomo and using Gurobi as my solver and it got stuck at 64.8% in the last 12 hours (0 0 223754.655 0 17483 635139.993 223754.655 64.8% - 76154s).  Below is a screenshot from my console.

Here is how I added Gurobi to my Pyomo code:

```
solver = po.SolverFactory('gurobi') # GNU Linear Programing kit
solver.options["MIGap"] = 0.1
```

And later when I was trying to optimize/ solve I used this line

```
solver.solve(model_obj, report_timing = True, tee = True, warmstart=False)
```

Apart from these lines, my codes are for my parameters, objective function, constraints and variables.

[image]

Comment: You will probably get a better response on or.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you @GregGlockner I will check that out.